# Returning VS NOT returning a promise in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a Firebase cloud function that routes events to another system by making http calls for every event.
I noticed that if I don't return the promise, the http gets called most of the times (can't be 100% sure). I don't care about the response

Execution time decreases substantially if I don't return it. (155ms vs 13ms)

Does anyone know if a non returned promise is guaranteed to execute?

Comment: Couldn't you just try that out?

Comment: anyone know why this is happen `Execution time decreases substantially if I don't return it.` ?

Answer (score 4):

If your function does not return a Promise, it may be killed prematurely by Cloud Functions. 
Also you might come across something like this in your console:
`Function execution took 60023 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`
This happens, when a function does not return a Promise to Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 2):

All types of functions except HTTPS type functions require that you [return a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) that becomes resolved when asynchronous work is complete.  If you don't do this, there is no guarantee that your work will complete, because the Cloud Functions runtime could clean up your function before the work is done.

It doesn't matter if you care about the response or result of the work, you should still be waiting until it's complete before allowing your function to terminate.

Comment: If I return a promise resolved, work in the same way?